# java.util.logger - FileHandler not creating file so Logger can write to it

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, logging, java.util.logging

I'm creating a Java Logger and trying to write to it in the console and into a file.

The console part is working fine, but the file never gets created. I want the file to exist in my target folder.

I'm using an Ubuntu computer with Eclipse IDE. I've given all permissions rwx, to the folder / file in the directory, yet the file is not created or if I manually create it, it is not written to.

```
    public class CukeLogs {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    FileHandler fileHandler = null;

    public CukeLogs() {

        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);

        try {
            fileHandler = new FileHandler("/home/ninad/Logs/CucumberLogs.log", true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
    }

    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }
}

ls -l -d /home /home/ninad /home/ninad/Logs /home/ninad/Logs/CucumberLogs.log
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root  4096 Aug 31  2017 /home
drwxr-xr-x 73 ninad ninad 4096 Aug 14 20:17 /home/ninad
drwxrwxrwx  2 ninad ninad 4096 Aug 13 20:53 /home/ninad/Logs
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ninad ninad    0 Aug 13 19:57 /home/ninad/Logs/CucumberLogs.log
```

Comment: If there are no exceptions , it means your file is created, may be not in the target directory but on the base directory of the web-app or console app.

Comment: Well, I've searched up and down my computer and cannot find it.

Comment: the problem is with your logfile path. the path you specified says that create a log at the same directory where this class exists. Change the path to any other folder, the log file will get create

Comment: I"m sorry, but I've changed the path, still nothing.